# Is it possible to have more vectors than the dimension of the vector space to be linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

By linear independence I understand that each vector in the vector space is not a scalar multiple of the other i.e. any one vector can be scaled independently without having to scale the other vectors.

But I seem to lack some understanding of this concept as I can think of three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that I find are linearly independent as in the below image (I could not make a better version of the graph).
[image]

Are these three vectors linearly dependant? If so how?

Answer (score 3):

For two vectors, your idea of linear independence is OK. But that is not the correct definition for more than two vectors.  This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) may provide more information.

Comment: It says each vector must not be a linear combination of the others (in order to be linearly independent). But I still can't figure out how the vectors I have in my mind (the eg. I gave) are linear combination of the two other vectors.

Comment: @Harold:  for the middle vector $v$ you can have $v = \frac{1}{2}u + \frac{1}{2} w$ (if say the end of $v$ is the midpoint of the ends of $u$ and $w$).

Answer (score 2):

No it is impossible.We know that 2 linearly independent vectors form a basis in $R^2$

Assume you are right and  there exist 3 linearly independent vectors at $R^2$ such that
$v_1,v_2,v_3$ so there must not be scalars different than 0 such that

$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=0$

we know that $\{v_1,v_2\}$ forms a basis so there exists $a,b$ such that

$c_3av_1+c_3bv_2=v_3$ $\Rightarrow$
$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3av_1+c_3bv_2=(c_1+c_3a)v_1+(c_2+c_3b)v_2=0$

according to fact that $\{v_1,v_2\}$ forms a basis

$(c_1+c_3a)v_1+(c_2+c_3b)v_2=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $c_1+c_3a=0 ,c_2+c_3b=0$

$c_2+c_3b=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $c_3=\frac{-c_2}{b}$

$c_1+c_3a=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $-c_3=\frac{-c_1}{a}$

so there exists a $c_3$ which is not $0$ that is a contradiction so your assumption is wrong

Comment: I think the proof is not good because you had assumed $c_1$ , $c_2$ are 0.

Comment: no i assumed they can only be 0 but found another solutions  which is the main point